# silverlight Grid ListBox row change color

Tags: silverlight, colors, listbox

I've got a silverlight phone app that i'm using to learn.  It's using web services to get the data.  I've got a Grid with a listbox inside of the grid.  I'd like to be able to have some of the text inside that listbox be a certain color based on conditions.

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0"  SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Operation}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTimeStart1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataID}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

So if the textblock which is bound to Status.. if that status = true i want to change the color of the row or even just that textbox.... whatever is easier.

i'm binding the data using the following code

```
 Me.MainListBox.ItemsSource = e.Result
```

Any help would be great

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Here is the modified code

```
  Private Class SomeData
    Inherits wsData.Data_Queries
    Public Property RowColor As SolidColorBrush
End Class
```

And here is where i'm creating a new instance of the class and binding it to the listbox

```
 Dim oSomeDataS As New List(Of SomeData)
    For Each x In e.Result
        Dim oSomeData As New SomeData
        With x
            oSomeData.DataID = .DataID
            oSomeData.DateTimeStart1 = .DateTimeStart1
            oSomeData.FinishFromStart = .FinishFromStart
            oSomeData.Operation = .Operation
            oSomeData.ShortDate = .ShortDate
            oSomeData.Status = .Status
            oSomeData.TblComputerNameID = .TblComputerNameID
            oSomeData.TblOperationID = .TblOperationID
            oSomeData.TblStatusID = .TblStatusID
            oSomeData.TblSiteID = .TblSiteID

            If .Status = "False" Then
                oSomeData.RowColor = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
            Else
                oSomeData.RowColor = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)
            End If
            oSomeDataS.Add(oSomeData)
        End With
    Next
    Me.MainListBox.ItemsSource = oSomeDataS.OrderBy(Function(o) o.Operation)
```

And the XAML code

```
 <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0"  SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Operation}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Foreground="{Binding RowColor}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTimeStart1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataID}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to do this.  The easiest to understand is to use an `IValueConverter` to bind the background color of the row to a color based on the status.  A good example of this can be found [here](http://dariosantarelli.wordpress.com/2007/07/15/wpf-using-ivalueconverter/) (the example is WPF, but the same principle applies in Silverlight).

Another way to do this is to wrap your data objects (that you get from e.Result) in a ViewModel object.  The ViewModel object would expose all the same properties as your data, but would also add one property (perhaps `RowColor`) where the getter returned a Brush or Color based on the value of `Status`.  You'd have to loop through your e.Results and create a new ViewModel for each one, add the ViewModels to a list, then set the ItemsSource to that new list of ViewModels.

Comment: Errrr.. i tried what you suggested.  I created a class that has a Public Property RowColor as Color.  looped through and made the property Color.Red and Color.Green based on Status.  in the XAML added Foreground="{Binding RowColor}".  when i run it that line doesn't show up.  If i change it to Foreground="Red", that shows up fine.  So is color not what i should be using for the RowColor property

Comment: Did you change your ItemsSource to be a collection of your new class?  Could you post code?

Comment: That looks right to me, though I admittedly don't know VB at all.  I figured this was C#.

Comment: it's working now.. if i put the rowcolor property into the webservice call.  What is special about it being in a webservice call instead of as a private class using it in a list.  my svc webservice call is doing something to it that allows it to be bound correctly.. i'm not sure what makes it work

Comment: when the data comes back as a service and i look at an item in the list, the difference that i'm seeing is that for every property in the item, there is a second property with the same name and Field added to the end.  just putting it out there in case someone can help

Comment: sorry for so many comments.. but the  added Field.. it's just it's private property that is auto generated in the Reference.vb file.  So figured that out.. but still do not know what one has to do in the iList to get the data to bind correctly

Comment: Oh -- it might be because your SomeData class is private.  It probably needs to be a public class so the binding system has access to its members.